# Is it possible to install Windows Sharepoint services over Windows Server 2003 installed on VirtualPC?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, virtualization, sharepoint

I have to work on Sharepoint. I want to install Windows Sharepoint services. However I don't have a Windows Server. Can I install Windows Server 2003 on a virtual PC and then install Windows Sharepoint services over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely can, even SharePoint 2007.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.

We use Server 2003 VPC's on Microsoft Virtual PC 2007 on a daily basis in our office for development purposes.

We run MOSS (SharePoint 2007), SQL Server 2005 and AD on a 2003 VPC with around 2GB of RAM with no issues.

There are numerous guides available online that detail how to go about setting this up, although let me know if you need a hand.

Cheers, Ben.